# Retrieving words that either end with EOL,Space or dont have any character. Regex

Tags: regex

I have a file that has words of these patterns

```
word word2
word
word word
word wordword
```

I need to count all the words that are just 'word' and not 'word2' or wordword.

I tried

```
$ grep 'word[^a-ZA-Z0-9 | $]' testWordCount.txt       
$ grep 'word[^a-ZA-Z0-9]' testWordCount.txt    
$ grep 'word[$| ]' testWordCount.txt
```

Sorry if some of these dont make sense. I am learning regex. And Sorry for not including the tool used for regex.

Comment: Please always include the tool or the language that support the regex you are using. They may be similar, but not the same, as the features and syntax can be different.

Comment: I guess `word! 'word'` shall count as words too - or don't they occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match lines using the following regex:

```
/\bword\b/
```

`\b` is a [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) that will match the start of a word, end of a word, start of a line, or end of a line.

You can test this expression at [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5Cbword%5Cb&input=word%20word2%0Aword%0Aword%20word%0Aword%20wordword).

---

I see you're using grep — this regex engine uses the `\<` and `\>` escapes for word boundaries.

```
/\<word\>/
```

---

Also, here's how you can count all the instances in bash:

```
cat testWordCount.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -c '\<word\>'
```

Comment: Yup. I was about to write that as well.

Comment: Updated to use word boundaries.

Comment: hmm I tried to grep '/\bword\b/m' but it wasn't available on my this shell. Isn't it available across all implementations?

Comment: Updated to include info on grep.

Comment: I am on the terminal emulator on gnome which I guess is running bash

Comment: Thanks Hans. I guess if I include them in quotes, I dont need to the leading slash in grep like this  grep '\<word\>' testWordCount.txt

Answer (score 0):

egrep -o prints the matching token on a single line, which can easily be counted in the end. `\b` means **boundary** or something similar.

```
egrep -o "\bword\b" words.txt | wc
```